# Array or List of Big Objects as parameter for AuraEnabled controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, list, array, big-object

Does Salesforce support passing an array or list of big objects as a parameter for an AuraEnabled controller method? In other words can I pass from a lightning component javascript controller an array of big objects directly to AuraEnabled controller method to save into the big object store? Or do I have to pass in JSON as a string an materialize an array or list on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse Yes. You are able to send list and additional attributes like this.

`var action = component.get('c.filterSave')
        action.setParams({
            "statement":component.get('v.fullList'),
            "name":component.find('saveFilterName').get('v.value'),
            "type":component.find('saveFilterType').get('v.value'),
            "ObjectType":component.find('saveFilterObjectType').get('v.value')
        });`

And You get the List and attributes on AuraEnabled controller like this.

`@AuraEnabled
 public static Filter__c filterSave(List<sObject> statement,String type,String name,String ObjectType){
        system.debug(statement);
        system.debug(name);
        system.debug(type);
        return null;
}`

Comment: Have you tried with a big object? I know you can with an sobject but I get an unreadable error if I use a custom big object. I had to first serialize it as JSON string then pass the string as the argument and finally deserialize it on the server side.

Comment: The curious thing is that you can pass a big object (i.e. __b type object) as a parameter but array or list of big objects fail.